# help with visudo

Tags: opensuse, sudo

I was trying to make shutdown without root user using visudo

I tried the following still it did not work for me

> hawk ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown -h now

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
hawk ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

then use

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

to shut the system down

Comment: yes.. I tried that but it did not work

Comment: If hawk is your username and you are logged in as hawk it should work.
What is the error message you get from sudo ?

Comment: this would not work thanks for your help.. to make it work we should use sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now, this works I had kinda avoided it for long anutime I tried it